# BigQuery: Deleting Duplicates in Partitioned Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have BQ table that is partitioned by insert time.
I'm trying to remove duplicates from the table. These are true duplicates: for 2 duplicate rows, all columns are equal - of course having a unique key might have been helpful :-(

At first I tried a SELECT query to enumerate duplicates and remove them:

```
SELECT
    * EXCEPT(row_number)
FROM (
    SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_column) row_number
    FROM
    `mytable`)
WHERE
    row_number = 1
```

This results in unique rows but creates a new table that doesn't include the partition data - so not good.

I've seen this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561860/bigquery-delete-rows-from-partitioned-table) which states the only way to retain partitions is to go over them one-by-one with the above query and save to a specific target table partition.

What I'd really want to do is use a DML `DELETE` to remove the duplicate rows in place. I tried something similar to what [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130324/bigquery-delete-statement-to-remove-duplicates):

```
DELETE
FROM `mytable` AS d
WHERE (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_column)
   FROM `mytable ` AS d2
   WHERE d.id = d2.id) > 1;
```

But the accepted answer doesn't work and results in a BQ error:

`Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN`

Would be great if anyone could offer a simpler (DML or otherwise) way to deal with this so I won't be required to loop over all partitions individually.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132644/5221944   ?

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, not sure how that is relevant for me as that answers assumes an additional column (loadTime) that is unique for each row. How can I adapt that to my case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kind of a hack, but you can use the `MERGE` statement to delete all of the contents of the table and reinsert only distinct rows atomically. Here's an example:

```
-- Create a table with some duplicate rows
CREATE TABLE dataset.PartitionedTable
PARTITION BY date AS
SELECT x, CONCAT('foo', CAST(x AS STRING)) AS y, DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL x DAY) AS date
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10)) AS x, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10));
```

Now for the `MERGE` part:

```
-- Execute a MERGE statement where all original rows are deleted,
-- then replaced with new, deduplicated rows:
MERGE dataset.PartitionedTable AS t1
USING (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dataset.PartitionedTable) AS t2
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the `not matched by target` clause more robust? table has many columns and some of the columns are repeatable arrays?

Comment: You could use SELECT with ANY_VALUE and GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one single SQL MERGE statement without creating extra tables.

```
-- WARNING: back up the table before this operation
-- FOR large size timestamp partitioned table 
-- -------------------------------------------
-- -- To de-duplicate rows of a given range of a partition table, using surrage_key as unique id
-- -------------------------------------------

DECLARE dt_start DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2019-09-17T00:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles") ;
DECLARE dt_end DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2019-09-22T00:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles");

MERGE INTO `gcp_project`.`data_set`.`the_table` AS INTERNAL_DEST
USING (
  SELECT k.*
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(original_data LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] k 
    FROM `gcp_project`.`data_set`.`the_table` AS original_data
    WHERE stamp BETWEEN dt_start AND dt_end
    GROUP BY surrogate_key
  )

) AS INTERNAL_SOURCE
ON FALSE

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  AND INTERNAL_DEST.stamp BETWEEN dt_start AND dt_end -- remove all data in partiion range
    THEN DELETE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ROW
```

credit: https://gist.github.com/hui-zheng/f7e972bcbe9cde0c6cb6318f7270b67a